# Using Heroku, Rails sort is incorrect on updated_at timestamp column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails 4.0 APP using PostgreSQL on Heroku.  I am trying to display a table that is my XLog or transaction log, showing the last five entries in reverse order by updated_at timestamp.  This works correctly on my local system.  When I push it to Heroku, it sorts incorrectly.

I have checked the Heroku database definitions and the column is correctly listed as a timestamp.  I have cloned the Heroku code back to my machine and verified that it is the same as what I pushed.  At this point, I don't know why it doesn't work on Heroku when it works locally.  And advice would be appreciated.

FWIW, the remote database and local database do not have the same data.

The code is:  (Last line of log_sort was added to act as a breakpoint that would still pass the correct result.)

```
  def self.last_objects object, count
    logs = XLog.where(object: object).last(count)
    log_sort = logs.sort_by{|log| log.updated_at}.reverse
    log_sort
  end
```

During execution to the breakpoint, you can see the variables passed:

[image: Code]

This is the local result with the correct sort:

[image: Local result]

This is the Heroku result with the incorrect sort:

[image: Heroku result]

This is the Heroku PostgreSQL table definition for updated_at:

[image: PostgreSQL table]

EDIT: View:

```
<% xlog = xlog_last(car.stock_number, 5) %>
...
<% xlog.each do |log| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= log.associate  %></td>
      <td><%= log.proxy      %></td>
      <td><%= log.action     %></td>
      <td><%= log.status     %></td>
      <td><%= log.message    %></td>
      <td><%= log.value      %></td>
      <td><%= log.updated_at %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Helper:

```
  def xlog_last(object, count)
    XLog.last_objects object, count
  end
```

EDIT:
I modified the sort_by to use an order method as follows.  The results did not change at all.  The same sorting error occurred and the exact same data was displayed in the exact same way:

New code:

```
def self.last_objects object, count
  logs = XLog.where(object: object).order(updated_at: :desc).first(count)   
end
```

Comment: And you're definitely displaying the timestamp you've sorted on (not created at for example)?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Yes.  Added view.

Comment: What is xlog set to?

Comment: @FrederickCheung XLog is a Rails class backed by a PostgreSQL table that I use to record  a structured result of each transaction.

Comment: I meant the local variable (or helper method) xlog, that you use in your view.

Comment: @FrederickCheung Of course you did!  I added the helper call in the view and the helper code above.  Thanks.

Comment: Odd, not sure what is up - looks ok to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gem was incorrectly sorting the view.  Correcting that issue fixed the problem.  Still unsure why it didn't show in test except possibly for the data differences.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `order` to influence the actual sql query. Right now you are using `sort_by` which is sorting the data after you read in from the database. The order in the db is based on how it was inserted and could be different from heroku and your local system. When you export from heroku, and then import it, the ordering of the tables probably changes too.

Comment: If this were the case, it would possibly impact my record selection but should have no impact on the order of the records as they are displayed, which is my question.  Correct?  And, as it is a log, the table isn't loaded but generated by transaction so the last physical five records should be the last records by timestamp.

Comment: correct, I can't explain the sort order of record you retrieved.  I'll try to experiment on one of my own tables in heroku...

Comment: I tried it on one of my tables on heroku using `sort_by` of a standard `updated_at` field with type `timestamp without time zone` and it sorted just fine.  I once had weird issue with a database on heroku (I don't remember exactly what) but I migrated it to a new heroku db and it solved my problem. Maybe that is something to try if there are no other solutions.

Comment: A few days ago, I issued Heroku pg:reset, ran a migration and re-seeded the database.  The problem did not change.  Would that be sufficient or would you think that I would need to define a wholly new database to Heroku?

Comment: @R_G I'm not sure... Might be worth if if there are no other things to try. Can you try another table in the same db with a date field to see how it behaves?

Comment: From my studies, it seems that heroku pg:reset is enough to completely redefine the database.  It requires a migrate and seed, or setup, to follow it.

Comment: I added edit to OP to show the use of order method to select records in desired order with same result in error.  Very curious.  I've also posted issue to Heroku, referencing this question.

Comment: FYI, Heroku support verified that a Heroku pg:reset is sufficient to reset the database.